# Why does the "partial_fit" method take much longer than the "fit" method

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm playing around with dictionary learning of the scikit-learn library and I wanted to build a dictionary based on a sequence of images. I tried to use the `partial_fit` method of `MiniBatchDictionaryLearning` and noticed it takes much longer to than `fit`. How my code looks (an example with lena):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import lena
from sklearn.decomposition import MiniBatchDictionaryLearning
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d

lena = lena()
lena = lena[::2, ::2] + lena[1::2, ::2] + lena[::2, 1::2] + lena[1::2, 1::2]
height, width = lena.shape

patch_size = (7, 7)
data = extract_patches_2d(lena, patch_size)
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], -1)
dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_components=100, n_iter=500,transform_algorithm ='lars', alpha=1,transform_n_nonzero_coefs=5,verbose=1)
dicObj = dico.partial_fit(data)
```

This takes ages to complete, while if I replace `partial_fit` with `fit` ... it takes a few seconds.

(I have scikit-learn 15.2)

Why is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that `partial_fit` is intended to be called on small batches of data.

The method `fit` actually does that same as `partial_fit` - it calls an online dictionary learning function. The difference is that `fit` uses the batch size indicated at the construction of the object, which by default is 3, whereas `partial_fit` works on the full data you provide (and this can take long if you provide too many samples. `partial_fit` is not made for that).

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/dict_learning.py#L1181) are the functions, so you can take a look at what happens.

Comment: I changed this batch size then, but this didn't help.

Comment: It won't -- `partial_fit` always uses the whole data, because it considers it one batch.

Comment: What you could do is loop over small batches in your data, e.g. `for i in xrange(0, len(data), 3): dico.partial_fit(data[i:i + 3])`

Comment: (however, you should obviously prefer `fit` in that case)

Comment: Seems your looping solution is still far slower than just a fit. I wonder why this is. 

What do you mean with "prefer fit in that case" ? In your looping example ? I can't seem to make sense of that.